# Data from mapped object onClick - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can you help me how can I get genre.id when user clicks on Button onClick function ?
Thank you

```
...
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <div className="App-wrapp">
        <div className="filter">
          {osa &&
            osa.map((genre) => (
              <Button key={genre.id} {...genre} onClick={thisFunction} />
            ))}
        </div>

        <div className="movie-list">
          {movies.length > 0 &&
            movies.map((movie) => <Movie key={movie.id} {...movie} />)}

          <button className="btn" onClick={showMore}>
            Load More
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

`<Button key={genre.id} {...genre} onClick={() => thisFunction(genre.id)} />`